rpc server is unavailable connecting to a systesm on another VLAN
I have a problem with RPC connecting to a system on a different VLAN, running the wbemtest.exe to s system on the same VLAN work soon, when i try to connect to a systesmon one of the other VLANS i get this error in powrshell
et-WmiObject : No such interface supported
At line:1 char:1

Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem –ComputerName test

  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand




wbemtest.exe error
Number: 0x800706ba
Facility: Win32
Description: The RPC server is unavailable.
Think they as the same error, checked with my Network admin and he clams all the ports needed are open.
Local firewall is off all the services are running the account i used to test with has domain admin access and i can't seem to trace this back to a root cause like a blocked port or service not running.
any ideas on this one
